# Postgresql assign a select query to variable in the function

Tags: function, postgresql, variables

I am using Postgresql 9.3 and wrote a function as below:

```
    create or replace function test(building text,floor text) returns void as $$
    Declare
    id integer;
    num integer := 0;
    Begin

    num=num+100

    id :=select to_number(
          (select 
              (select code from buildings where name=building) || floor 
              || (select num::text)),'99999999'
    );

    update table set col1=id;

    End;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

What I expect is that my `id` variable will be assigned a number value `example: 12502100` from the `select to_number(...)` query.

However I got the below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 10: source :=(select code from buildings where name='I3')
```

How can I assign the query result (with some string operations) into the variable id?

I am also failed with `Select Into id...` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need use `SELECT` for function evaluation.

```
id := to_number((SELECT code FROM buildings WHERE name = building) 
                                                      || floor || num::text,
                '999999999');
```

other possibility (and usually better) is using function in expression list (result field list)

```
id := (SELECT to_number(code || floor || num::text, '99999999') 
          FROM buildings WHERE name = building)
```

Use `SELECT` only when you need a query to data, not for function or variable evaluation!

Comment: your 2nd method gives me error " mismatched parentheses at or near ")"", the 1st method is working.

Comment: @Xianlin: sorry, fixed there was one parentheses more

Comment: how do you do it with multiple variables and one statment? i.e. you want to fill var1 and var2 with (SELECT field1, field2 FROM buildings WHERE name = building); var1 should contain field1 result and var2 should have field2 result.

Comment: @thames:  You have to use SELECT INTO statement for multiple variables