# postgresql if else select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a query that will compare first
first condition was to compare 
the year now and
get the maximum year of view view_delinquency_allquarter
then, it will execute the first query
else second query

```
BEGIN
IF 
    select max(ctaxyear) as ctaxyear,
        (select cast ( (SELECT EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP 'now()'))  as int ) as yearnow) as yearnow
    from view_delinquency_allquarter 
    where ctaxyear > year_next
THEN
   select * from view_delinquency_allquarter;
ELSE 
   select * from view_delinquency;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267048/postgresql-assign-a-select-query-to-variable-in-the-function) as well as [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) use `declare var` and then assignment `var := (your query result)`